# Prove that an upper triangular matrix is invertible if and only if every diagonal entry is non-zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that an upper triangular matrix is invertible if and only if every diagonal entry is non-zero.
I have proved that if every diagonal entry is non-zero, then the matrix is invertible by showing we can row reduce the matrix to an identity matrix. But how do I prove the only if part?

Comment: Do you know the permutation based definition of a determinant?

Comment: No.. I don't think I can use determinant in this proof

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is an $n\times n$ triangular matrix, consider the system of equations
$$A\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$$

If last $0$ in the main diagonal is at position $j$, you can solve for $x_n$, $x_{n-1}$,...,$x_{j+1}$. But what happens with $x_j$? Must it be $0$?

But if $A$ had an inverse we would have
$$A^{-1}A\mathbf x=\mathbf x=\mathbf 0$$

Can you complete the reasoning?

Answer (score 2):

If not every diagonal entry is zero, then we can show that the matrix does not have a full rank anymore (can you do it?). Therefore it is not invertible.

Comment: Perhaps you prefer edit your deleted answer and then undelete it :)

Comment: @ajotatxe I would. But deleted answers do not appear on the IOS application. They should fix this.

Comment: Ok, sadly I can't do it for you because I can not undelete your post.

Answer (score 0):

*Proof.* ($\Rightarrow$)

Let $A=[a_{i,j}]_{n\times n}$ be an invertible upper triangular matrix. Suppose that $A$ has a diagonal entry that is zero, i.e., $a_{k,k}=0$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $1\leq k<n$ (note that if $k=n$, then A would have a zero row, thus making A singular, which should not be the case). Then, the homogenous equation $Ax=0$, i.e.,

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1,1} &&\cdots &&a_{1,n}\\
0 &\ddots\\
\vdots & &a_{k,k} &&\vdots\\
&&&\ddots\\
0&&\cdots&0&a_{n,n}
\end{array}
\right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_k\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{array}\right]=0,$$

where the $k^{th}$ row is the last row whose entry on the main diagonal is zero, will have a nontrivial solution since

$$\underbrace{\overbrace{a_{k-1,k-1}x_{k-1}}^{\text{if $k\neq1$}}+a_{k-1,k}x_k}_{(i)}+\underbrace{a_{k-1,k+1}x_{k+1}+\cdots+a_{k-1,n}x_n}_{equals\text{ }to\text{ }0}=0,$$

wherein *(i)* implies that we have, indeed, a nontrivial solution. Thus, a contradiction exists since if $A$ is invertible, then the homogenous equation $Ax=0$ must only have the trivial solution.

Therefore, all of the diagonal entries of $A$ must be nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another quick solution:

**1.** we know that for any matrix $A \in M_{n}$,  $$det(A) = \lambda_1 \times \lambda_2 \dots ... \lambda_n$$
where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

**2.** Also, we know a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is non-zero.
**3.** Finally, eigenvalues of an $n \times n$ triangular matrix is its diagonal entries.

Now, from above, we conclude that a triangular matrix $A$ is invertible iff all diagonal entries are non-zero. Otherwise, the product of them-which is equal to the detrminant- is zero and it will be singular.