# Prove A is invertible if its diagonals are non-zero

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

The following answer was from this question:
[Prove that an upper triangular matrix is invertible if and only if every diagonal entry is non-zero.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1260495/prove-that-an-upper-triangular-matrix-is-invertible-if-and-only-if-every-diagona)

Can someone explain the purpose of the linear combination that is in the solution and how it proves a non-trivial solution? What are they using the k-1 row?

*Proof.* ($\Rightarrow$)

Let $A=[a_{i,j}]_{n\times n}$ be an invertible upper triangular matrix. Suppose that $A$ has a diagonal entry that is zero, i.e., $a_{k,k}=0$, where $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $1\leq k<n$ (note that if $k=n$, then A would have a zero row, thus making A singular, which should not be the case). Then, the homogenous equation $Ax=0$, i.e.,

$$\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_{1,1} &&\cdots &&a_{1,n}\\
0 &\ddots\\
\vdots & &a_{k,k} &&\vdots\\
&&&\ddots\\
0&&\cdots&0&a_{n,n}
\end{array}
\right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
\vdots\\
x_k\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{array}\right]=0,$$

where the $k^{th}$ row is the last row whose entry on the main diagonal is zero, will have a nontrivial solution since

$$\underbrace{\overbrace{a_{k-1,k-1}x_{k-1}}^{\text{if $k\neq1$}}+a_{k-1,k}x_k}_{(i)}+\underbrace{a_{k-1,k+1}x_{k+1}+\cdots+a_{k-1,n}x_n}_{equals\text{ }to\text{ }0}=0,$$

wherein *(i)* implies that we have, indeed, a nontrivial solution. Thus, a contradiction exists since if $A$ is invertible, then the homogenous equation $Ax=0$ must only have the trivial solution.

Therefore, all of the diagonal entries of $A$ must be nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a mistake, besides their answer wasn't accepted, they were talking about the k-th row as the row in which the value of $$a_{k,k}=0$$
yet they were pointing out to the k-1 th row.

I would recommend looking at the characteristic polynomial of A, $$P_{A}(\lambda)=det(\lambda I-A)$$

Since the matrix is triangular then computing the determinant is as easy as multiplying the diagonal values:
$$det(\lambda I-A)=(\lambda - a_{11})*(\lambda - a_{22})*...*(\lambda - a_{nn})$$

Suppose that A has a diagonal entry that is zero, without the loss of generality, let's say $$a_{11}=0$$

then,
$$det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda*(\lambda - a_{22})*...*(\lambda - a_{nn})$$
thus we can conclude that 0 is an eigenvalue of A, or in other words, A is singular.

---

Alternative way to prove it without computing the characteristic polynomial of A would be to perform elementary operations on A, since we suppose that A has a diagonal entry that is zero, then by performing Gaussian elimination we'll eventually find that $$rank(A)=n-1$$ therefore $$dimP(A)=n-rank(A)=1$$
that means that there exists $$v\in F^n$$ such that $$Av=0$$

*Or another way to finish the proof would be:*

A is invertible if and only if $$rank(A)=n$$
since we found that $$rank(A)=n-1$$ 
A is not invertible in contradiction to our base assumption, which A is invertible.

---

In order to do it without ranks or determinants, you can take a look at the other answer or try to write the equations and deduct what you need about $$x_{k}$$ assuming that A has a diagonal entry that is zero at the kth entry.

Comment: Could you explain this by trying to prove it the way they were trying to (i.e. showing that Ax = 0 has a nontrivial solution). I'm not familiar with determinants at this point

Comment: Yes im familiar with rank

Comment: Thank you for your proofs! But Doesn't your rank proof only prove that if all the diagonals of A are non-zero then A is invertible? I'm trying to prove if A is invertible then its diagonals are nonzero. I think the most intuitive way for me is to try to prove Ax =0 has a nontrivial solution. But I cannot visualize this

Comment: true, it's just that you will get that $$x_{k}$$ doesn't have to be 0 and therefore Ax=0 has a non trivial solution. I'd suggest writing it down.

Comment: So because $a_{kk}$ = 0, $x_k$ can be anything for the right hand side of the equation to still 0? What about all the elements to the right of $a_{kk}$which are non-zero?

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter because we already proved that one scalar can be nonzero

Comment: since $$a_{n,n}\neq0$$ we get that $$x_{n,n}=0$$you reverse your way from bottom to top and you get that all of elements to the right will be multiplied with 0.

Comment: I personally don't like this "brute forcing" method, I find the other proofs I wrote down to be quite nice, also liked @Matematleta proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99026/discussion-between-atn-and-holdsworth).

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to appeal to determinants, or ranks of linear transformations, you can brute force it as follows: Suppose $U$ is invertible. Then, there is a matrix $A=[a_1,\cdots, a_n]$ of column vectors such that $AU=I.$ Writing this as a system of $vector$ equations, you get

$a_1u_{11}=e_1$

$a_1u_{12} + a_2u_{22} = e_2$

$\cdots$

$\cdots$

$a_1u_{1n} + a_2u{2n} + \cdots + a_nu_{nn} = e_n$

Start from the top and work down, solving for the $a_j$. You get $a_j = (e_j −\sum^{j−1}_{k=1} a_ku_{kj} )/u_{jj};\  j = 1, \cdots, n.$ So, if $U$ is invertible, the inverse, which is unique, $must$ be given by the above formula. On the other hand, if any of the diagonal elements is zero, then this formula cannot hold and so $U$ does not have an inverse.

Comment: Just to confirm.. A matrix of column vectors is just a row vector right? i.e the shape of A is n x 1 ?